# how to calculate the incremental total amount everytime you enter a value in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

The Total Amount is incrementing(single cell:H2) when value is entered in the same cell(G2).Example today if you enter in G2 the value of 30 the total amount in H2 is 30 and when you enter tomorrow in G2(same cell) the value of 50, the total amount in H2 should be 80.Then when you enter again 80 in the same cell(G2)the next day, the total amount should now be 160.Hope you could shed a light on this.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just use VBA to read G2 and H2 and output the sum back to H2.  You'll probably want to use the change event for the G2 cell to trigger this, though you could just use a button.